# Average weight Lab

Tags: java

Attached is my code for a lab. I must use a while loop. The goal is to ask for an "object" and the objects mass, calculate the weight (mass * 9.8) and loop until a weight of -5 is given. I have to also count the valid inputs, weights, and average weight, then display them. I am struggling with how to average the weights in the while loop, and store the valid weight values.

Sample Output after Part 3:

```
Enter the object's name> 
Honda Accord
Enter Honda Accord's mass> 240 
Honda Accord is too heavy. 
Enter the object's name>
Feather
Enter Feather's mass> 
0.001
Feather is too light. 
Enter the object's name>
Running Shoes
Enter Running Shoe's mass> 
2.5
Running Shoe's weight is 24.50Newtons.
Enter the object's name>
Kiwi
Enter Kiwi’s mass> 5.5
Kiwi's weight is 53.90Newtons.
Enter the object's name> 
Panda
Enter Panda’s mass>
-5
-----
Total input count: 4Total 
valid count: 2Total 
valid weight input: 78.40
Average valid weight: 39.20
```

My code

---

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MassWeight {

    public static void main(String args []) {
        double mass = 0;
        int inputCount = 0;
        int validCount = 0;
        double totalValidWeight = 0;
        double averageValidWeight = 0;

        while (mass != -5){
            //Ask user for an object's name
            System.out.println("Please enter the name of the object:");
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
            String objectName = keyboard.nextLine();
            //Ask for the object's mass. Reference the name.
            System.out.println("Please enter " + objectName + "'s mass:");
            inputCount = ++inputCount;
            mass = keyboard.nextDouble();
            //Calculate the weight (weight = mass * 9.8)
            double weight = (mass * 9.8);
            //Write an if statement that checks the weight.

                if (weight < 1000 && weight > 10) {
                System.out.format(objectName + " weighs %.2f Newtons.\n", weight);
                validCount = ++validCount;
            }
                else if (weight < 10 && weight > -5) {
                System.out.println(objectName + " is too light!");
            }
                else if (weight > 1000) {
                System.out.println(objectName + " is too heavy!");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Total input Count: " + inputCount);
        System.out.println("Total valid count: " + validCount);
        System.out.println("Total valid weight input: " + totalValidWeight);
        System.out.println("Average valid weight: " + averageValidWeight);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are asking how to update `totalValidWeight` and `averageValidWeight` by valid `weight` input values. To update `totalValidWeight`, you can add this line in the first if statement:

```
totalValidWeight += weight;
```

To get `averageValidWeight`, add this line after the while loop:

```
averageValidWeight = totalValidWeight / validCount;
```

Comment: Yes, this was it. Thank you.